# Are you allowed to apply this to a problem?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that we have a dihedral group D_n. We have that F_1 and F_2 are distinct reflections with the property that F_1F_2 = F_2F_1. We wish to prove that F_1F_2 = R_180 degrees. Am I allowed to say that applying R_180 to F_1F_2 we obtain R_180(F_1F_2) = (F_2F_1)R_180?

Comment: A simple answer is no since $D_n$ is not abelian.

Comment: That is true, but elements in D_n associate. @Eoin

Comment: Then you may use association to prove this. However, I would need additional reasoning to go from $F_1F_2 = F_2F_1$ to $R_{180}(F_1F_2) = (F_2F_1)R_{180}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $D_n$ denote the dihedral group of order $2n$ acting on the vertices of the $n$-sided regular polygon.  The dihedral group $D_n$ is generated by the elements $r$ and $s$, where $r$ denotes rotation and $s$ denotes the reflection of the polygon about the axis through vertex 1 and its center. It can be verified that $sr = r^{-1}s$.  Every reflection is of the form $sr^i$ for some $i \in \{0,1,\ldots,n\}$.

Let $F_1 = sr^i$ and $F_2 = sr^j$ be reflections that are distinct, so that $i \ne j$. Then $F_1 F_2 = F_2 F_1$ implies $sr^i sr^j = sr^j sr^i$. Using the facts $r^i s = sr^{-i}$ and $s^2=1$, we get that the left-hand side equals $s (r^i s) r^j = s (s r^{-i}) r^j = s^2 r^{-i+j}$ and the right hand side equals $s^2 r^{-j+i}$, whence $r^{2(j-i)}=1$. But the rotation $r$ has order $n$ and $i-j \ne 0$. Thus, $2(i-j) =n$, and $F_2 F_1 =r^{i-j}=r^{n/2}$ is rotation by 180 degrees (assuming $n$ is even).